# Middle Korean Pronunciation

Tags: korean

How did the final consonants of each syllable sound in Middle Korean?

English Wiktionary (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EA%B3%B6) states that 곶(flower, 꽃) sounded kòs̚, but not kòt͡s. Can you tell me why?

Comment: I don’t really know anything about Middle Korean (or much about any form of Korean), but presumably it’s considered that affricates could not appear syllable-finally, where they were simplified to, in this case, the fricative part of the affricate (unreleased here). It’s very common cross-linguistically for consonants and clusters to be simplified in final position and then appear in their ‘full’ forms in inflected or derived forms where it’s no longer in word-final position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [page 80 of the 2012 tome *The Languages of Japan and Korea*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Languages_of_Japan_and_Korea/I7PTXPq_nSAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA80&printsec=frontcover) on Middle Korean (한글 has been added by myself):

> MK [Middle Korean] observed implosivization (unrelease) of syllable-final consonants, except *s* {ㅅ} which was, unlike in CK [Contemporary Korean], not neutralized to *t* {ㄷ} but spelled *s* {ㅅ}, suggesting it was pronounced [s], as in *mos* {못} [mos] ‘pond’ versus *mot* {몯〯} [mot] ‘unable’.

So where did final *c* ㅈ fall then? From [page 65 of the 2011 reference *A History of the Korean Language*](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/A_History_of_the_Korean_Language/2AmspKX3beoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&&pg=PA65):

> In Middle Korean, /s, c, ch/ no longer remained distinct before a pause, but were, rather, pronounced as the sibilant [s].

According to the above, final /ts/ in 곶, as attested in the 1447 龍飛御天歌 용비어천가 *Yongbi eocheonga* would have been pronounced [s], different to the Korean language of today.

There are many cases of this lexeme for "flower" being spelled with a ㅅ instead of ㅈ in the period. From the 月印釋譜 월인석보 *Worin Soekbo* of 1459:

> **곳** 닐굽 줄기ᄅᆞᆯ 가져 겨샤ᄃᆡ

... which in Modern Korean would be "꽃 일곱줄기를 가져 가시되...", in English: *[She] was holding seven [stalks of] flowers, and [...]*. One 2002 article [중세국어 곡용 어미의 특징 파악 "Characteristics of Middle Korean Declension Endings"](https://www.reportshop.co.kr/report/921893) has the following claim (emphasis mine):

> 중세국어에서 체언의 특정 말음은 자음으로 시작하는 조사나 휴지(休止) 앞에서 8종성(ㄱ, ㄴ, ㄷ, ㄹ, ㅁ, ㅂ, ㅅ, ㅇ)으로 교체된다. 이것은 주로 말음이 ‘ㅈ, ㅊ, [ㅂ], ㅍ, ㅌ’ 자음군인 경우에 일어난다.
>
> 예)　**곶 ~ 곳 (花)**, ~ 즛(貌), ~밧(外)

Roughly translated: "In Middle Korean, certain final phonemes of substantives are substituted [either] with postpositions that start in a consonant or with one of eight pre-pausal coda consonants (ㄱ, ㄴ, ㄷ, ㄹ, ㅁ, ㅂ, ㅅ, ㅇ). This mainly occurs in situations involving the final consonants ㅈ, ㅊ, [ㅂ], ㅍ, ㅌ."

There is also [earlier evidence from the 1400 Korean-Chinese glossary](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/A_History_of_the_Korean_Language/2AmspKX3beoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&&pg=PA166) 朝鮮館譯語 *Cháoxiǎn-guǎn Yìyǔ*, where 花 "flower" is glossed as 果思 (in modern Mandarin, *guǒsī*), that 思 representing a final /s/ of 곳. Note that final /t/ was represented with whichever Chinese character had an Early Mandarin reading with a glottal final, e.g. 筆 "writing brush" was glossed as 卜, which is *bǔ* in Modern Standard Mandarin but had a glottal ending in Early Mandarin, and represented 붇〮 (which only later became 붓 in Korean).

All this confirms that final ㅈ/ㅊ had all merged to final ㅅ [s] by the Late Middle Korean of the 15th century, with this final [s] subsequently merging with final ㄷ and ㅌ into [t̚] [throughout the later 16th century and complete by the 17th century](http://chiyukit.sakura.ne.jp/Koreananalogy.pdf).

Comment: Not necessarily even intentional, but I like the glossing of a flower as the ‘thought of a fruit’. There’s a poetic reality to that.

Comment: Thank you, it is very helpful! I'm actually a Korean interested in this field, but there have been few people to ask it in Korean communities.